# Hoisting order with IIFE involved, specific example

Tags: javascript, iife, hoisting

I came across this code:

```js
var myVar = 'foo';

(function() {
  console.log('Original value was: ' + myVar);
  var myVar = 'bar';
  console.log('New value is: ' + myVar);
})();
```

Questions:

1. Is IIFE hoisted to the top before global `myVar`?
   1a. IF it is, is it executed before global `myVar` is declared?
2. In IIFE I get `undefined` first, and `bar` second. What is the behind the scenes order of execution in IIFE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The IIFE is an expression, not a statement, so no it is not hoisted.
2. `var myVar` inside the IIFE is hoisted to the top of the function scope, but the assignment is not. The following is equivalent:

```js
(function(){
   var myVar;
   console.log('Original value was: '+ myVar);
   myVar = 'bar';
   console.log('New value is: ' + myVar);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Patrick Roberts' answer is excellent, but I wanted to make something clear, there is nothing specific to IIFEs here, all functions work the same, whether they are immediately invoked or not

```js
var myVar = 'foo';

// f1 : creates a variable inside the scope with the same name
function f1 () {
    console.log(myVar);   // Logs undefined
    var myVar = 'hi';
}

// f2 is the same as f1
function f2 () {
    var myVar;
    console.log(myVar);   // Logs undefined
    myVar = 'hi';
}

// f3 declares before logging
function f3 () {
    var myVar = 'hullo';
    console.log(myVar);   // Logs the inner value of the variable
}

function logOuterVar () {
    console.log(myVar);   // Logs the global var
}

f1();
f2();
f3();
logOuterVar();
```

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. The main point is that IIFEs are not statements so they are not hoisted.

Comment: The title being “Hoisting order with IIFE involved” and the question reading “What is the behind the scene order of execution in IIFE ?” (which could be understood as “inside an IIFE”) I thought anyone coming to this page should be made aware that the involvement or not of an IIFE is in fine irrelevant to the subject matter

Comment: I just wanted to add that there is nothing oesoteric about what happens inside of or around an IIFE.