# In JS Engine, does the IIFE's execution context get created & exited BEFORE or AFTER the variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, function, stack, executioncontext

Since all IIFEs are function expressions, like a function declaration, does JavaScript allocate memory BEFOREHAND(before running any code) for a function expression that is lexically inside the global execution context?

If yes, since [functions get stored in memory first before variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246653/6897265), the IIFE's execution context will exit even before the variables are declared because it is called immediately.

```js
(function(){
   console.log(foo);  // (1)
})();
var foo=0;
```

(1): should return Uncaught ReferenceError: 'a' is not defined Error, but instead of a's value being undefined. Why?

Comment: Why should this throw a `ReferenceError`? Variables declared with `var` get hoisted to the "top".

Comment: *"since functions get stored in memory first before variable declaration"* That only applies to function **declarations**. Function *expressions* are evaluated when they are encountered in the source code, just like any other expression.

Comment: @Andreas **if** IIFEs were allocated in memory (which they are **not** as I know now), according to that above link, the function would be created first & called even before other variables were declared, so any variables accessed inside the iife would be undefined

Comment: As Felix already said, it looks like you're missing the **E** in IIFE. Those are expressions and are therefor not hoisted.

Comment: Partial dupe: [Hoisting order with IIFE involved, specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417054/hoisting-order-with-iife-involved-specific-example)